# How do I get gawk to transpose my data into a csv file

Tags: awk, transpose

I have a bunch of input text files that look like this:

```
   measured       5.7       0.0000    0.0000    0.0125    0.0161    0.0203    0.0230    0.0233    0.0236    0.0241
                            0.0243    0.0239    0.0235    0.0226    0.0207    0.0184    0.0147    0.0000    0.0000


   measured       7.4       0.0000    0.0000    0.0160    0.0207    0.0260    0.0295    0.0298    0.0302    0.0308
                            0.0311    0.0306    0.0300    0.0289    0.0264    0.0235    0.0187    0.0000    0.0000
```

Each file has a couple of lines like that.

I want to take all of these files, cut out the 'measured' and first number (eg. 5.7 and 7.4) and put them in a CSV file so they will be sorted into columns like this:

[image: CSV file]

My gawk command is

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\n" }
/measured/ { c=2; $1=$2=""; $0=$0 }
c && c-- { $1=$1; print }
```

Which I run as part of a for loop in windows `for %f in (*) do (gawk -f column.txt %f ) >> finaloutput\burnup.csv`

And that just produces a long column of numbers like this:

[image: column]

How do I get gawk to transpose the data into separate columns instead of one big long column?

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable **textual** sample input and expected output so we have something we can test a potential solution against and then we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

$1=$2="";

this was the problem. you threw away exactly what you wasted (the 5.7) by having "measured" and "5.7" both go blank. The rest of the work became a futile exercise of re-cranking fields without the data you need.

c=2 only set the times you want to loop it it didn't save any of the variables before the =""

Also, any particular reason why you need a loop for those files? just cat (or pv, my preferred method) it over to gawk (i think mawk2-beta might run this at least 60-70% faster than gawk 5.1.0. AWK is the insane tool that has a much easier time than python or R when it comes go shoving it with gigs at a time.

Perhaps also consider using gnu grep (not the gd BSD one like on my mac - the syntax and escaping required just to match ABC \n XYZ on that thing is surreal) ?

I think this might be one of those great use cases for the --text flag (so it won't go screaming on irregularity bytes here and there), the -h flag (when you're  sourcing from multiple files), and the -o flag to capture only the portion you need. But i'm not 100% too sure if a concurrent grep like that might exhibit any inconsistencies or not ?

i'm super novice in python or perl so can't help much there

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I don't want the "measured" nor the "5.7".  I want the rows of numbers after them, and to have them vertical and ultimately transposed into a spreadsheet.

Comment: ahhhh now i understood what you meant. try this. tested on mawk2 beta. Should also work in mawk 1.3 and gawk - see the new solution below

Answer (score 0):

Try this new solution. Tested on mawk2-beta should work elsewhere. This should handle the transpose automatically without having to use multi-dimensional arrays because the regex inside RS already will flatten that whole thing into 1 column.

Setting TOTCOL should only occur once. which is handled by setting FS to newline, so whenever it's at end of the line, FS is at least 2, if not more.

Furthermore, it doesn't need to assume it's 9 or 11 columns at all. It'll be auto-computed. So unless the input file has more than 1 billion columns, this trick be an issue.

I backed up the NR by 2 initially so the % wouldn't loop back to 0 one spot too early.

```
mawk2 'BEGIN { TOTCOL = 1E9; NR -= 2; FS = ORS; OFS = "";

           RS = "([\n]*[ \t]+measured[ \t]+[^ \t]+)?[ \t]+"; 
       } 
       (NR < TOTCOL && NF > 1) { 
                                 TOTCOL = 2 * length(outS); } 
       (NR == TOTCOL)          { 
                                 OFS = "\t" ; }
       { 
          outS[NR % TOTCOL] = outS[NR % TOTCOL] OFS $1 ; } 
   END { 
         for (trspd in outS) { 
                                print outS[trspd]; } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed all the issues. This will work across gawk / mawk-1.3 / mawk2. Reason being mawk-1 must initialize the array first else it'll whack out.

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { TOTCOL = 1E8; FS = "[\n]+"; NR -= 2; OFS = "";
    
     RS = "((^|[\n]+)[ \t]+measured[ \t]+[^ \t]+)?[ \t]+";  
     outS[""]++; 
     delete outS[""];
  
  } ( NR  < TOTCOL && NF > 1 ) { TOTCOL = 2 * length(outS);    
  } ( NR == TOTCOL           ) { delete outS[-1];
                                 OFS = "\t" ;
  } { outS[NR%TOTCOL] = \
                        outS[NR%TOTCOL] OFS $1 ; 
  } END { trspd = 0; 
          nx = length(outS); 

          do { 
               print outS[trspd];
          
          } while (++trspd < nx) }'
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's close to what I want, except that it puts all the data into one big long column.  I want each data file to have its own column, like above.  I thought I could just transpose it with Excel, but Excel puts it into one long row.

Comment: aren't they ? i took your sample data, and they're transposed to 18-rows per column, then stacked left to right, into a 2D table. The first part of the code indeed makes it 1 long column. That's the outS array comes in - they're formatted into their new rows along each read, so the print loop in the END { } section should already be pre-transposed.

Comment: It puts the data into one long column but separates each section with a blank cell.  It doesn't seem to transpose it.  Gawk doesn't seem to read the section after END.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{                       # read empty line separated blocks
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)                  # loop from 3rd field to the end
        a[i]=a[i] sprintf("%10s",$i+0)  # append to NF in indexed array elements
}
END {                                   # in the end
    for(i=3;i in a;i++)                 # output
        print a[i]
}' file
```

Output:

```
     0         0
     0         0
0.0125     0.016
0.0161    0.0207
0.0203     0.026
 0.023    0.0295
0.0233    0.0298
0.0236    0.0302
0.0241    0.0308
0.0243    0.0311
0.0239    0.0306
0.0235      0.03
0.0226    0.0289
0.0207    0.0264
0.0184    0.0235
0.0147    0.0187
     0         0
     0         0
```

It's dumb (since I'm lazy) in the sense that `sprintf` uses static 10 spaces for the right-justified output.

Comment: I tried that but it seems to be misreading my input files.  It starts off getting the first row in correct order in the column, but then it leaves off the first two fields in the second row and skips ahead to the second row of the next input file.

So I get output like this:

0         0
0         0
0.0125 0.0125
0.0161 0.0161
0.0203 0.0203
0.023 0.023
0.0233 0.0233
0.0236 0.0302
0.0241 0.0308
0.0311 0.0455
0.0306 0.0448
0.03         0.044
0.0289 0.0423
0.0264 0.0386
0.0235 0.0344
0.0187 0.0274
0         0
0         0

Comment: That output has values that are not even in the sample data so what else has changed? Post that data as a file somewhere in the internets and post the link.